# Keep getting error ORA-02438 when trying to create table

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get my code to run but it keeps giving me this error. I'm new to SQL and haven't gotten used to it yet and I keep trying to fix it but I can't seem to get it to work. I've put both tables into the description code below.

```
 Create table Account
(
    Account_Number Number(7,0)
      Constraint PK_Account_Account_Number Primary Key
      Constraint NN_Account_Account_Number Not Null,  
    Account_Balance Number(13,2)
      Constraint NN_Account_Account_Balance Not Null
);


  Create table Investor
(
  Investor_Number Number(7,0)
      Constraint PK_Investor_Investor_Number Not Null,
  First_Name Varchar2(25)
      Constraint NN_Investor_First_Name Not Null,
  Last_Name Varchar2(30)
      Constraint NN_Investor_Last_Name Not Null,    
  Street_Address Varchar2(35)
      Constraint NL_Investor_Street_Address Null,
  City Varchar2(25)
      Constraint NL_Investor_City Null,
  Province Char(2)
      Constraint CK_Investor_Province Check (Province in ('__'))
      Constraint NL_Investor_Province Null,
  Postal_Code Varchar2(7)
      Constraint CK_Investor_Postal_Code Check (REGEXP_like(string,'[A-Z]-[0-9]-[A-Z]-[0-9]-[A-Z]-[0-9]'))
      Constraint NL_Investor_Posta_Code Null,
  Area_Code Number(3,0)
      Default '780'
      Constraint NN_Investor_Area_Code Not Null,
  Phone_Number Number(7,0) 
      Constraint NN_Investor_Phone_Number Not Null,
  Account_Number Number(7,0) Not Null,
      Constraint FK__Investor_Account_Number --Name of Constraint
      Foreign Key (Account_Number) -- Foreign Key Column name
      References Account(Account_Number)-- name of table and column trying to reference,
  );
```

Comment: How are you executing the commands?  Sqldeveloper, or some other way?

Comment: What s `string` in the `regexp_like`?

Comment: im using sql developer

Comment: @AlexPoole i saw it in an example online and i put it in postalcode to be able to continue the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check constraint in `Postal_Code` is referring to `string` instead of the actual column name; it should be:

```
  Postal_Code Varchar2(7)
      Constraint CK_Investor_Postal_Code Check
          (REGEXP_like(Postal_Code,'[A-Z]-[0-9]-[A-Z]-[0-9]-[A-Z]-[0-9]'))
      Constraint NL_Investor_Postal_Code Null,
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e362eda7fdebbb7788518e72a152f786)

The error you are getting is because the parser is interpreting `string` as an identifier, and assuming it's the name of another column, even though it isn't. There isn't anything else it could obviously be though,so it's not entirely unreasonable.

Comment: I think "Constraint NL_Investor_Posta_Code Null" is also an error. To make something not allow nulls is a constraint, but to allow nulls isn't.

Comment: I wasn't paying that much attention... it seems to be valid though. And intentional. Odd... if I remember I'll have a play tomorrow and see if it actually does anything.